# getjson request fails when running on localhost

Tags: javascript, getjson

getjson request fails, when i run in my remote hosting i not have problems, but when i run in localhost the request fails, what's wrong? i´m getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

My directory:
[image]

CLIENT

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var getdetails = function(id) {
        return $.getJSON("20.php", {
            id: "1"

        });
    } //END FUNCTION getdetails

    var searchData = function(user) {

        getdetails(user)

            .done(function(response) {

                if (response.success) {

                    $.each(response.data.users, function(key, value) {

                        $.each(value, function(userkey, uservalue) {});
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Fail");
                }
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            });
    }; //END FUNCTION searchData


    searchData("1");


    var socket = io();


    socket.emit('room', prompt('suscribe to channel...'));




});
```

SERVER

```
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static('./public'));
var users = [];
var nicks = new Array();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('room', function(room) {



socket.join(room);

    });


});




http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: What is in your JSON file?

Comment: The first character of the data at the URL you are requesting  is `<`, which isn't valid JSON. What that has to do with the Node.JS code you've provided, I have no idea. It look likes it should be coming from a PHP program, which you haven't provided. Possibly the `<` is from `<?php` and somewhere you are serving up the PHP code to the browser without executing it on the server.

Comment: {
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0"
  }
}

Comment: @Quentin Yes im sure that < is from <?php because i not having problems in my web hosting, and when i run on localhost i have this problem, why then the code is not executed?, what's the problem? or what i missed here?

Comment: @SergioDiaz — Are you serving up the PHP file using the **static** data plugin for Express?

Comment: Yes im doing that

Comment: Well, that's the problem then. PHP is dynamic.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page